# Laravel: pass data to one view but redirect to other

Tags: php, laravel

I have a value that the admin can change on his admin.blade page. I want this value to be displayed on the user's page(user.blade).
The is field an 'amount' field on the admin site that can be changed (through modal on a form). The submission of the form calls an action which does the following:

```
public function changeAmt(){
auth()->user()->update([
            'amt' => $data->input('newamt')
        ]);

        return redirect('/adminpage');
    }
```

I want to be able to redirect to the admin page, but at the same time i want the 'amt' value to be passed to the user side's user.blade page as well.

> How can I send the  'amt' value to the user's page (user.blade)

I'm not sure if I should be using `view::share('what goes here')` and do something or have a different approach. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: you can share data to all view using `view composer`

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik i'm not familiar with it, could you give an example please?

Comment: Refer this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views), `Sharing Data With All Views` topic name

Answer (score 1):

You can use flashed session data https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

```
return redirect('/adminpage')->with('amt', $value);
```

Comment: the /adminpage is the one its being redirected to, but how do I sent the value to user.blade page (route '/userpage)?

Comment: you should store the value in a session or cookie.

Comment: could u pls give me an example regarding how I would be able to do that

Comment: // Store a piece of data in the session...
    session(['key' => 'value']);

// Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
    $value = session('key');


https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session